# SVG still receives clicks, even if pointer-events: visible/painted

Tags: html, css, svg, visible, pointer-events

Basically, I have a couple .svg images put into an `<img>` tag on my HTML page like that:

`<img src="images/corner.svg" alt="menu" class="menu" onClick="Fade();"/>`

All of those images are overlapping with each other. They have the same size but different content.
I'm now trying to make only the content of those images clickable.
With `pointer-events: visible;` or `pointer-events: painted;` in CSS that seemed to be possible, but i can't get it work like that. The image still receives clicks at every point in it and not only on the content part.

I tried `pointer-events: none;` on the top image and that disabled clicks on the top image, which sounded like there was no mistake in the HTML or CSS code.

I created those .svg images in Illustrator CC with a transparent background, so normally there can't be content, and I exported it with the following options:

(sorry for this being in german)
[image: picture of SVG settings]

I have no idea where the problem could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using an `<img>` tag. They work like rasters even when the data is SVG i.e. the individual items don't really exist, it's just a picture which you can either have as entirey clickable or not.

If you want the drawing to be interactive you'll need to use an `<object>` or `<iframe>` tag and then you can make the individual shapes clickable or not by using the pointer-events attribute.

You could also include all the svg data inline in the html file but if you did that you'd need to make sure all the id attributes were unique.

Comment: Or `<svg>`, don’t forget to mention that! ;-)

Comment: Okay, I changed all to `<object>`, put all shapes to `pointer-events: none;` and added `pointer-events: all;` with the javascript event right inside the svg files of the shapes i want to be clickable, but those events still won't get triggered.

Comment: If works if add `pointer-events: all;`in the main HTML file, but then again the other shapes won't be clickable, because they are overlapping.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a jsfiddle so we can see where you're going wrong as it should work.

Comment: Okay i figured something out! I've put the .svg files right into the HTML code with the `<svg>` tag added the `pointer-events:all;` only to the visible parts. I've also tried other options like with `<object>` and `<iframe>`, but for me it only works how I did it now. Thanks for helping though!

Answer (score 10):

I've had success inlining the SVG, setting the pointer-events to none for the SVG elements, and then setting the pointer-events for the path element within the SVG to fill. [Here's a CodePen example](http://codepen.io/patrickmcd/pen/YPgQNE).

```
svg {
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
}

path {
  pointer-events: fill;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me

```
svg {
  pointer-events:none;
}
svg *{
  pointer-events:auto;
}
```

don't hesitate to add `!important` in case it has conflict with your current style.