# How can I pass ONLY clicks through a SVG with pointer-events?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, click, pointer-events

I have a SVG overlaying a div with a button. I know that i can pass mouse-events through the SVG by setting "pointer-events: none;" for my SVG. However when I do this the SVG wont recognize mouse-events anymore.

```
<body>
  <div id="website">
    <form action="input_button.htm">
      <p>
        <textarea cols="20" rows="4" name="text"></textarea>
        <input type="button" name="Text 1" value="show text" 
         onclick="this.form.text.value='Test'">
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="svgRect">
    <svg width="1845" height="140">
      <rect id="r0"></rect>
    </svg>
  </div>
</body>
```

I want my SVG to be able to recognize when the mouse is over it but pass clicks to elements (divs/ buttons / ...) underneath itself.
So my SVG should only be the target of hover-events and my button should be the target of click-events.

Among some other approaches I tried it like this: - Nothing worked.

```
.on("mousedown", function(d,i){
   d3.select("#r0")
     .style("pointer-events", "none");
   d3.select("#website")
     .style("pointer-events", "auto");}
.on("mouseup", function(d,i){
   d3.select("#r0")
     .style("pointer-events", "auto");
   d3.select("#website")
     .style("pointer-events", "none");
}
```

The idea was to disable pointer-events when I press the mouse-button and enable them again when I release it.

Does anyone know a solution or work-arround for this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Curious as to the purpose of this SVG. Overlaying a form seems counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: The purpose of my project is to create svgs that overlay some parts of a website. These svgs need to react to some hover-events. I understand that this doesnt seem intuitive, without knowing the whole background ;)

Comment: Overlays are overlays...you can't pick and chose whether **parts** of them are click-through.

Comment: So for "overlays" there is no difference between "hovering" and "clicking"? I dont want to have special **parts**, I want the SVG to pass through clicks, while still recognizing hover. Pointer-events doesnt seem to differ between hover and click... you either get both or nothing.

Comment: Fundamentally you have something that is covering the Form. You either let everything through or nothing. Other than awkward HTML restructuring I think you're stuck with it.

Comment: it is possible with `elementFromPoint()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. It is possible to traverse through all underlying elements with the `elementFromPoint(x,y);` function. I wrote a  helper-function that checks if the first selected element is a SVG - if it is one its' display is set to "none" and the next element is selected.

```
function get_element_under_svg(x,y){
    var resulting_element;
    var first_element = document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
    //check if first_element is a svg
    if (first_element.nodeName == "rect") {
      _display = first_element.style.display;    //save display of svg
      first_element.style.display = "none";      // make svg invisible
      resulting_element = document.elementFromPoint(x,y); 
      first_element.style.display = _display;    // reset display
    } else {
      resulting_element = first_element;
    }
    return resulting_element;
  }  
  return lower_element;
}
```

At the end of the day I set `pointer-events: auto` for my SVG and for my div:

```
#website{
  pointer-event: auto;
}
svg{
  pointer-event: auto;
}
```

And to my svg I added the following:

```
.on("click", function(d,i) {
  var element = get_element_under_rect( mouse.x, mouse.y );
  element.click(); // simulate click on the underlying element
});
```

With this approach my SVG is still capable to receive hover- or click-events, while it is able to pass clicks to underlying elements. 
See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint

Thanks for the other approaches!

Answer (score 8):

Here is a easier solution:
Keep   `pointer-events: none;` in the svg, but add `pointer-events: fill` to the poligon, path or whatever your button is, with this, the empty space is transparente, but the button is sensible to click

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29319009/2594391

Comment: Good thought but does not seems to be working

Comment: does work for me in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Here there is a way, I give you an example

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: #e54d42;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.link {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica, Verdana;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 40px;
}
.link:hover {
  color: #e59a95;
}

.mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
}

.mask {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.svg-not-transparent {
  pointer-events: fill;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.svg-not-transparent:hover {
  fill: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="link">En: I am reacheable even if there is a big SVG omer me <br>But not over the  SVG shape<br>Esp: Puedes darme click aún cuándo hay un SVG sobre mi.<br>Pero no sobre el poligono</a>
  <svg version="1.1" class="mask" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1980 1320" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1980 1320;" xml:space="preserve">
     <polygon class="svg-not-transparent" points="1277.7,0 567.8,1337.5 1980,1337.5 1980,0 "/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

: http://codepen.io/jesuscmd/pen/EyEyoP

Answer (score 0):

You could disable pointer events on the SVG, but add another div of the same size that is a transparent parent of both the SVG and the form. You could then listen to the hover events on the transparent parent:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var container = document.getElementById("container");

container.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  log("SVG mouse over");
}, true);
container.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  log("SVG mouse out");
}, true);

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  log("BTN click");
}, false);

var out = document.getElementById("out");

function log(s) {
  out.innerHTML += s + "<br>";
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
#svgOverlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
#out {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="website">
      <form action="input_button.htm">
        <textarea cols="20" rows="4" name="text"></textarea>
        <input type="button" name="Text 1" value="show text" onclick="this.form.text.value='Test'" id="btn"></input>
      </form>
    </div>
    <svg id="svgOverlay" width="300" height="100">
      <rect width="100%" stroke="black" height="100%" fill="gray" id="r0" opacity=".5"></rect>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div id="out"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't think this will allow clicking of elements below the extra div **and** the SVG.

Comment: Yes it does, because the clicks go through the transparent div and the non-transparent svg has pointer-events disabled - just run the snippet to see that you can click the button below the svg.