# Click throw png or svg

Tags: html, svg, png

Lets say we have an element `<div>` and above that element we have image png or svg code. If that png or svg have empty spots, how can we let clicks pass to the `div` element? And to complicate that even more, in fact i have canvas below the png or svg which have to be handled, so `<label>` will not solve the issue.

Comment: You might try an imagemap.  I don't know how they handle open spaces in the map.  Also, you could break the image down to a collection of images so that there literally *are* gaps that the click event will "pass through"

Comment: For SVG, see [Passing Mouse Events through SVG Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46534633#46535144). I fear that will not work for PNG.

Comment: After long experience, i do agree with you.